# Unable to send mail via javax

Tags: jakarta-mail

I currently have a mail server up and running. I can log into it via

mywebsite.com/roundcube/

From this site I can send and receive email appropriately.  Logs show all the mail come in and out and it's fine.  I've sent from here to my gmail account and back.

However, what I really want to do is send some mail from java using javax mail.

I've tried configuring as follows:

```
    final String username = "myusername";
    final String password = "mypassword";

Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.debug","true");

        // Get the Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        session.setDebug(true);
```

When I go to send the message via

```
Transport.send(message);
```

I get the following output:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.0-b01
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I can telnet to the box via localhost on port 25

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JavaMail FAQ, [Why do I get an error such as java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect when connecting to my mail server using JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#ipv6perm).

> Set the System property "java.net.preferIPv4Stack" to "true".